# using insert iterators without std::copy

Tags: c++, iterator

I have an insert iterator and an iterator to the element I want to insert but I am not allowed to use `std::copy`.

This is what I found on the c++ reference page:

```
std::copy (bar.begin(),bar.end(),insert_it);
```

This is also what I want to do but I can't use `std::copy`. Is there another way?

Comment: I guess, that first of all, you should tell your teacher, that "tighten that screw, but you can't use a screwdriver" is a worst possible way to teach people things...

Comment: So do you want to insert a single element (which is what you describe), or a sequence of elements (which is what `std::copy` with an insertion iterator does)?

Comment: @Spook Judging by this forum there do seem to be an awful lot of teachers like that out there. Or maybe it's that because they're bad teachers a disproportionate number of their students end up here.

Comment: Do you really have "an insert iterator"? Then just say `*insert_it = new_element;`. Or do you mean you have an iterator pointing to the location at which you want to insert the element?

Comment: @James Yes, you're right! The actual problem was that I wanted to insert several (non consecutive) single elements (so maybe std::copy could not have helped me anyway?) but the answer I got was the one I needed and I was able to solve the problem.

Kerrek SB Yes I had "an insert iterator" thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto first = bar.begin();
auto last = bar.end();
while (first!=last)
{
  *insert_it = *first;
  ++insert_it;
  ++first;
}
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to +1 this, because, while it is pretty much an implementation of `std::copy`, it's not quite clear that this is what the asker *really* wants, and I think an answer should contain some explanation. (I am occasionally guilty of just dumping code, but I do it as a comment, and at least try to include comments within the code). May I suggest you explain how this code works, and how it might be useful to the asker.

Comment: You don't need to dereference `insert_it` if you know its type is `insert_iterator`.

Comment: @jrok And you don't need to increment it either.  Both incrementation and dereferencing are basically no-ops, which return `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provides moves the content from bar.begin() to bar.end() into the insert iterator. I'm confused by the term you used `insert` and `std::copy` will not insert anything , just copy content.

To actually insert elements in the container you can use this:

`your_container.insert(insert_it, bar.begin(),bar.end());`

You can find an example here for `std::vector` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert/insert/

Hope this helps,
Raxvan.

Comment: `copy` writes to an "iterator".  The destination can be any mutable iterator type, including an OutputIterator.  An insertion iterator inserts.  (If he has access to the container, your suggestion is better, but he said that he had an insertion iterator, not the container.)